# Script the tallest title in the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such type of [catаlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHHil.jpg), which was made with li and float:left . how can I select the tallest title of product from string. For examle I have 2 strings of product and the tallest title in the first row have 2 string of text , that is mean that all title in this string should be equal the height of the tallest title, in the second row the tallest title has 3 string of text , that is mean that all title in this string should be equal the height 3 string even if it has 1 string

here is my markup [click](http://business-dev4.alleanza.ru/mu/vikkar/02_psd_catalog.html)

```
<ul class="b-products__list">
   <li class="b-product">
    <div class="b-product__img-wrap"><a href="" class="b-product__img-link" title="товар"><img src="_mod_files/ce_images/product-1.jpg" alt="" class="b-product__img"></a></div>
    <h3 class="b-product__title"><a href="" class="b-product__link">Интеллектуальные вентиляторы вентиляторы</a></h3>
   </li>
   <li>...</li>
```

[image]

i have a similar script , but it doesn't look in rows

```
function setEqualHeight(columns)
{var tallestcolumn = 0;
columns.each(
function()
{currentHeight = $(this).height();
if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn)
{tallestcolumn = currentHeight;}
});
columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some markup? Also, did you try using `display: inline-block` in the CSS instead?

Comment: yes, of course [link](http://business-dev4.alleanza.ru/mu/vikkar/02_psd_catalog.html) , yes I've tried it now but the problem is that the border-bottom should be on the same level in each row.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question instead of a link, you will get much more attention and help

Comment: What is your problem? It seems to me that your current approach is working. Can't you just use table for that products list?

Comment: the problem is that the border-bottom of li with class='b-product' should be on the same level in each row. No, I can't use table

Answer (score 0):

You have several options with HTML and CSS alone. For one, it is tabular data, and nothing speaks against using a good ol' `<table>` for this.

If you cannot do that, you can use `display: inline-block` like discussed in [this article](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/). The final result will be identical to the one you have at the moment, but it will be stable, i.e., not looking like this, if some content doesn't match:

[image: misguided display:float]

Thirdly, if you can't use a table and need equal height, go through each row like this:

```
var lis = $('.b-products__list').find('li'),// all list elements
    lis_length = lis.length,
    row_width = 3, // the number of columns
    i, tmp_h3s, tmp_height;

// loop through all lis, but with row_width instead of `1`
for (i = 0; i < lis_length; i += row_width) {
  tmp_height = 0;

  // fetch all relevant headings in this group
  tmp_h3s = lis.slice(i, i+row_width).find('h3');
  tmp_h3s.each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    if (tmp_height < h) {
      tmp_height = h;
    }
  });
  tmp_h3s.height(tmp_height);
}
```

(The trick is to use the [splice](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) method).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is combine all rows into container and change the height for each `<li>` in this container, if it is not possible or you don't know how many items can contains your row, you can distinguish each row by offset().top here is an example below that works with your page. It can be refactored, but the main idea is clear

```
function getHeight(offset){
var max = 0;
var curr = 0;
$('.b-product__title').each(function(){
    curr = $(this).height();
    if($(this).offset().top == offset && curr > max){
        max = curr
    }
});
return max;
}

$('.b-product__title').each(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset().top;
    var height = getHeight(offset);
    $(this).height(height);
});
```

hope it helps